# not able to add Data to child tables with OneToMany mapping

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am not able add dummy data in child tables while using OneToMany mapping in spring boot. please help me with it
Here is Entity class (only sending join table):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "recipeIngredients",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
private List<RecipeIngredient> recipeIngredientList;


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "recipeSteps",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "step_id"))
private List<RecipeSteps> recipeSteps;


public Recipe(Long user_id, String title, String category, String recipeDescription) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.title = title;
    this.category = category;
    this.recipeDescription = recipeDescription;
}

//getter setter
```

here is function for dummy data :

```
public String recipe(){         
Integer i = 1;
Long l = Long.valueOf(i);
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe(
            l,"Maggie","Veg","2 min Noodles"
    );
    System.out.println("----------------" + recipe.getRecipeDescription() + " "
            + recipe.getCategory() + " "
            + recipe.getTitle() + " "
            + recipe.getId());
    List<RecipeIngredient> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new RecipeIngredient("salt","2kg"));
    list.add(new RecipeIngredient("sugar","5kg"));
    for (RecipeIngredient iff : list) {
        System.out.println("--------------------"+iff.getName() + " " + iff.getIngredientQuantity());
    }
    List<RecipeSteps> steps = new ArrayList<>();
    steps.add(new RecipeSteps("Step 1","chopping","chop the mf vegetables"));
    steps.add(new RecipeSteps("Step 2","boiling","boil them rock hard"));

    recipe.setRecipeIngredientList(list);
    recipe.setRecipeSteps(steps);
    recipeRerepository.save(recipe);
    return "recipe Here";
}
```

Here is database table :
[image]

and Here error

```
Hello from AuthTokenFilter JWTnull
----------------2 min Noodles Veg Maggie null
--------------------salt 2kg
--------------------sugar 5kg
Hibernate: insert into recipe_info (category, recipe_description, title, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into recipe_ingredients (ingredient_quantity, name) values (?, ?)
2021-12-01 18:16:10.692  WARN 375589 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2021-12-01 18:16:10.692 ERROR 375589 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'recipe_id' doesn't have a default value
2021-12-01 18:16:10.786 ERROR 375589 --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'recipe_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: How does the mapping in RecipeIngredient and RecipeSteps look like? If it is bidirectional you need to set the reference instance for each ingredient or step instance.

Comment: Its Unidirectional but can you please explain it more or should I try with Bidirectional association.

Comment: In case of one-to-many usage I would suggest a bidirectional setup. Based on your insert statements in the logs, hibernate tries to persist the recipe_info and recipe_ingredients before even persisting the Recipe itself. So it does not know which recipe to use and thats why it fails.
Maybe try in recipe 
'@OneToMany(mappedBy = "recipe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<RecipeSteps> recipeSteps;'

and in recipe_info '@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id") private Recipe recipe;'  and if you add recipe info objects you need to make sure the recipe info referrences the recipe too

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Yes I solved it... actual issue was reference table was creating recipe_id out of nowhere. I put orphanRemoval = true and it worked

Comment: Thanks for your help I was able to learn more about JPA